# Learning curves for multiclass classification

Tags: python, cross-validation, multiclass-classification, overfitting-underfitting

I am working on a multiclass classification problem. I want to know whether my model is overfitting or underfitting. I am learning how to plot learning curves. My question is, is the order of steps I have done correct?

1. Scaling
2. Baseline model
3. learning curve to see how well baseline model performs
4. Hyperparameter tuning
5. Fit the model and predict on test data
6. Final learning curve to determine if the model is over or under fitting

The first plot is after I do CV for baseline model and before hyperparameter tuning, and the second plot is done at the end, after hyperparameter tuning and fitting the best hyperparameters to the final model

[image]

[image]